# Convert field from a Listitem to a List<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I'm querying a Sharepoint Online database using CAML and getting the requisite ListItemCollection that it returns.  I am only interested in one field of this ListItemCollection and am converting it to a List<T> for use by another function.  Is there a way to do this using LINQ and a lambda function?

My current code, which works fine, is below (listItems is of type ListItemCollection from the Sharepoint Client Namespace).

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>();

foreach(ListItem itm in listItems)  //listItems is type ListItemCollection
{
   theList.Add(itm["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString());
}
```

It seems like it should go something like

```
theList = listItems.ToList<string>(  i => i["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString()  );
```

or

```
theList = listItems.Cast<ListItem>().ToList<string>(i =>
               i["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString());
```

but i'm having trouble with the conversion.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select` to project each item in a sequence into another sequence (which can then be added to a list):

```
var emails = items.Select(item => (string)item["Email_x0020_Address"])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ahhh...the light turns on.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Servy for your answer....it should work fine, but it returns a "method is not supported" error.  After some more research, there was another answer in the microsoft forums...i guess it has to become an IEnumerable first, then a List??

```
 List<string> theList = 
          (listItems.ToList().Select(item=>(string)item["Email_x0020_Address"]) as 
          IEnumerable<string>).ToList();
```

or like this...

```
   List<string> theList = listItems.AsEnumerable().Select(item =>
                         (string)item["Email_x0020_Address"]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
var emails = (from ListItem listItem in items.ToList()
              select new Customer
               {
                 EmailAddress = listItem["Email_x0020_Address"] != null ? 
                         listItem["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString() : string.Empty
               }).ToList();
```

OR

```
List<Customer> lstCustomerEmails =
               (from ListItem listItem in items.ToList()
               select new Customer
               {
                 EmailAddress = listItem["Email_x0020_Address"] != null ? 
                         listItem["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString() : string.Empty
               }).ToList();
```